# Portable way of getting a fd filename of a commnd stdout in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, portability, file-descriptor

I am pretty sure I am missing terminology on this and it's probably the reason google failed me. Is there a portable and simple way of redirecting the standard output to multiple commands.

In other words how could I fix this portability issue:

```
$ /bin/bash -c '(echo to your mom) | tee >(read b; echo "agent 1 reports $b") >(read b; echo "agent 2 reports $b")  >(read b; echo "agent 3 reports $b")'
to your mom
agent 1 reports to your mom
agent 2 reports to your mom
agent 3 reports to your mom
$ /bin/zsh -c '(echo to your mom) | tee >(read b; echo "agent 1 reports $b") >(read b; echo "agent 2 reports $b")  >(read b; echo "agent 3 reports $b")'
to your mom
agent 1 reports to your mom
agent 3 reports to your mom
agent 2 reports to your mom
$ /bin/sh -c '(echo to your mom) | tee >(read b; echo "agent 1 reports $b") >(read b; echo "agent 2 reports $b")  >(read b; echo "agent 3 reports $b")'
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Note thet the output ordering is not the issue, `/bin/sh` yielding with an error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use named pipes:

```
#!/bin/sh

fifo1=$(exec mktemp --dry-run)
mkfifo "$fifo1"
( read b; echo "agent 1 reports $b" ) < "$fifo1" &

fifo2=$(exec mktemp --dry-run)
mkfifo "$fifo2"
( read b; echo "agent 2 reports $b" ) < "$fifo2" &

fifo3=$(exec mktemp --dry-run)
mkfifo "$fifo3"
( read b; echo "agent 3 reports $b" ) < "$fifo3" &

echo to your mom | tee "$fifo1" "$fifo2" "$fifo3"

rm -f "$fifo1" "$fifo2" "$fifo3"
```

Usage:

```
sh script.sh
```

Output:

```
to your mom
agent 2 reports to your mom
agent 1 reports to your mom
agent 3 reports to your mom
```

That's the science. And with functions you can make technology to make piping easy for you based on your preference.

Comment: cool!, Do you think one could do away with the named pipes and just use file descriptions somehow for brevity?

Comment: @fakedrake With normal shells you probably can't do that. The only pipe you can create with normal shells is the usual pipe `|`.